# help me with this sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6

im using mysql and vb6 to execute this query..

```
 sql = "select user_id, fname, middle, lname from users where NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM accounts where accounts.user_id = users.user_id) "
```

what i'm trying to do is to get the list of records from table users where the user_id does not exist on table accounts. i was successful on this, however, im having a problem with my vb code..

i want that on the change event of my textbox, if the user type 1, all the records starting with 1  will be displayed..i tried doing this but to no avail..i got syntax error
..by the way, the nuser_id is the value of text box..

```
sql = "select user_id, fname, middle, lname from users where NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM accounts where accounts.user_id = users.user_id) and user_id like'" & nuser_id & "%'"""
```

any idea? thanks..

Comment: Your second snippet is vulnerable to sql injection. Don't use string concatenation to substitute in query data like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql = "select user_id, fname, middle, lname from users where NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM accounts where accounts.user_id = users.user_id and accounts.user_id like'" & nuser_id & "%')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but might work:

```
sql = "SELECT users.user_id, fname, middle, lname FROM users WHERE users.user_id NOT IN (SELECT accounts.user_id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.user_id = " & nuser_id & ") AND users.user_id = " & nuser_id & " LIMIT 1"
```

I strongly suggest, that you cast the variable `nuser_id` to integer (or sql escape it if your ids aren't numbers).

Btw: Your original code was leaking a whitespace after the `LIKE`.